# 64bit datatype for host and device in OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

I need a 64bit datatype for bit manipulation in OpenCL. In the manual
https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html
they say ulong is "An unsigned 64-bit integer". But when I prepare the data on the host, 
it cannot grow bigger than 32bit unsigned.

After that, I read that unsigned long (on the host) is only a 32bit Type, just as unsigned int. I also 
tried cl_ulong, but it also seems to have 32bit.

What is the right 64bit datatype for host and device?

Comment: Could you put some codes from kernel and host please

Comment: Removed cryptography tag, no idea why that was used.

Answer (score 2):

`cl_ulong` is 64bit datatype, it matches the cl kernel side `ulong`. 
This is ensured by the spec, even on 32bits machines.

It is defined as `typedef uint64_t cl_ulong __attribute__((aligned(8)));` in **platform.h** file.

Can you detail why you "think" is 32bit? 
Can you show some code?

Comment: 1) When I print CL_ULONG_MAX,  I get 4294967295 which is 2^32 - 1. 2) When the value of startoffset exceeds 2^32, it doesn't go until 2^64 as expected: while (step < nKernels) {
  cl_ulong startOffset = step++ * INT_MAX;

Comment: Sorry for the form of the code; I must read how to use the stackoverflow comment formatting.

Comment: Please add some code. We are not sure if the error is in the host code, printing, kernel or elsewhere.